# How to Create Eclipse plugin with external jar using Ant build

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin

I wrote an eclipse plug in, and built it from a batch file, using Ant.

Now I wrote a small java application(jar file), which I need to use as an external jar, from my plug-in code.

I googled a lot, and did the following:(Since I build it via batch file and command line, I don't write here the steps it can be done with the Eclipse UI, but the command lines)

1. In the MANIFEST.MF, I added these lines:

> ```
> Bundle-ClassPath: libs/DataManager.jar,
>  .
> ```

```
  and I remembered to add two empty lines, as needed...
```

2. In the .classpath file, I added these lines:

> < classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/DataManager.jar"/>

3. I edited my build.properties file, so now it looks like:

   > > source.. = src/
   >
   > ```
   >  output.. = bin/ bin.includes = META-INF/,\
   >                 .,\
   >                 plugin.xml,\
   >                 icons/,\
   >              libs/,\
   >                 libs/DataManager.jar
   > ```
   >
   > src.includes = libs/ jars.extra.classpath = libs/DataManager.jar
4. My build.xml contains this line:

> < target name="Bin" depends="init,@dot.nestedJars" unless="Bin"
>   description="Create jar: com.ish.epish @dot.">
>
> ```
> < delete dir="${build.result.folder}/Bin"/>
> < mkdir dir="${build.result.folder}/Bin"/>
>     <path id="@dot.classpath">
> ```
>
> < pathelement location="libs/DataManager.jar"/>

Now, build command line is:

> java -jar 
>   "C:\Eclipse\4.3.2\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar"
>   -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -buildfile "%CD%\com.ish.epish\build_temp.xml"

the state is that the jar created successfully, but on run time it fails, and I cannot know why. 
in additional,when I try to see the jar file content using BeyondCompare software, I can see that the "libs" folder, which I wished the jar to contain, is not a part of the jar.

I must mark that when I do all this through the Eclipse IDE UI - the process  runs easily and correctly, but I have to do it through the command line...

can you help me please?

Comment: Something you can try: In Eclipse, go to file -> Export... -> JAR. Several of these wizards have the option of creating an ANT script aswell. That will serve you as a good starting point to make changes to.